# Store dropdown value and apply to checkbox when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I am trying to change the 'value' of the checkbox when an item is selected from a dropdown list and then the checkbox is clicked. I have got a jquery function storing the value from the dropbox (I havent included the code from the dropdown list because it works fine and is not an issue. class is the element from the dropdown list obviously):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).on('click', '.class', function() {
        var clicked = $(this).text(); 
    });
</script>
```

Ive looked around and cant find how to apply the 'clicked' variable to the 'value' of the checkbox when a checkbox is clicked.

Comment: jquery is no where related to HTML. unclear question. [Read how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @AlivetoDie at the bottom it is quite clear what im asking "how to apply the 'clickeditem' variable to the 'value' of the checkbox when the checkbox is clicked"

Comment: Question is incomplete. In what way do the drop down items and check boxes relate? i.e. to assign the checkbox as selected, are the drop down items 'Room 1', 'Room 2'.... ?

Comment: Formatted code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to store the selected dropdown item into a variable like so:

```
var clickeditem;

$(document).on('click', '.studentclass', function() {
    clickeditem = $(this).text();
});
```

Now that you have stored the selected item into a 'global' variable:

```
$(document).on('click','.room',function(){

    //Do some checks to ensure checkedItem is not empty etc...

    //Then
    $(this).attr('value', clickeditem);
});
```

Comment: So should I have the check for checkbox and the setcheckboxitem in the same script code?

Comment: Yes, can you give me an example of the string that would be assigned to the clickeditem var you defined? I'll then update the answer accordingly

Comment: The strings in the dropdown list are names like 'John Smith'

Comment: I think I misunderstood the question. When you click 'John Smith' what checkbox item are you wanting to be checked?

Comment: Oh ya I think you did. When 'John Smith' is clicked I dont want any checkbox to be checked yet. The user will select a checkbox after selecting an item from the dropdown, and then 'John Smith' will be store in the value of that checkbox.. does that make sense?

Comment: Alright is there a way I can 'alert' out the value to see if its changed??

Comment: after using `$(this).attr('value', clickeditem);` you could just `console.log($(this).attr('value'));`